# Stickyjs not working since upgrading to jquery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Since upgrading to the latest jquery in the latest wordpress theme the stickjs is not working 100%.

It sticks but it does not unstick when hitting a certain height.

I cant tell if its the calculation which does not work anymore or there is an issue with the plugin.

You can see the plugin here:

http://stickyjs.com/

You can see the jquery from the plugin here:

https://github.com/garand/sticky/blob/master/jquery.sticky.js

The jquery I am using is as follows:

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("#back_to_top_side").sticky({

topSpacing: 80,
bottomSpacing: (jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(".finish").offset().top) - 800

});

});

</script>
```

I am getting no errors within my javascript log.

Help would be grateful :)

Comment: Works for me. Can you create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @jgillich - I cant as its a wordpress theme